# Entering time data quickly using code for a specific range of cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

What API code do I use if I want to quickly enter 24 hour times (without entering the colon and still retaining time formatting) for a certain range of cells?

I know the following code works for Excel spreadsheets, but not for Google spreadsheets. 
How would I get this to work in Google?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim vVal

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Intersect(Target, Range("c1:zz5000")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    With Target
        vVal = Format(.Value, "0000")
        If IsNumeric(vVal) And Len(vVal) = 4 Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            .Value = Left(vVal, 2) & ":" & Right(vVal, 2)
            .NumberFormat = "[h]:mm"
        End If
    End With

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you not do this with a formula, i.e. an extra cell with a formula that converts your 1700 into a time value.

Comment: Yeah, it's looking like I'm going to have to do that afterall.